# tshark: extract rtp payload of the codec G.723

Tags: unix, wireshark, pcap, tshark

In order to extract the RTP payload from a **pcap file** captured by wireshark, I'm using tshark with the command

```
tshark -nr stream.pcap -i wlan1 -R 'rtp && ip.dst==192.168.1.64' -T fields -e rtp.payload
```

this succeeded with the codecs g.729 and ilbc but with the codec **g.723** it wasn't the case. I think that this problem is due to the fact that the field payload of the rtp protocol doesn't exist any more (when consulting the wireshark).

Any idea of how to extract the payload of the codec g.723?

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:
used rtpxtract.pl from 
[here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SULLR/Net-Inspect-0.303/tools/rtpxtract.pl)

then used ffmpeg to convert it to format user can listen to. like MP3.

`ffmpeg -f g723_1  -i ${infile} ${outfile}.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you have just to disable the protocol g723 in wireshark in the item **Enabled Protocols** from the **Analyze menu** then the field "payload" will appear in the protocol rtp and the command

```
tshark -nr stream.pcap -i wlan1 -R 'rtp && ip.dst==192.168.1.64' -T fields -e rtp.payload
```

will succeed!